# C# - Expected a method with 'xxx' signature

Tags: c#, function

I have two projects (MenuSystem and GameBrain) in one solution for a board game. Across projects i have enum EMenuNavigation which is placed in MenuSystem and link added to GameBrain.

I have a MenuItem class:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    private string Title { get; set; }
    public Func<EMenuNavigation>? MethodToRun { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => Title;

    public MenuItem(string title, Func<EMenuNavigation>? methodToRun)
    {
        Title = title;
        MethodToRun = methodToRun;
    }
}
```

My function looks like this:

```
public static EMenuNavigation HvH()
{
    var board = new Board(8);
    var gameMenu = new Menu(EMenuLevel.Game, "> Game <");
    gameMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Make A Move", board.MakeMove));
    gameMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Cheat", null));
    gameMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Save The Game", null));

    board.ShowBoard();
    
    return gameMenu.RunMenu();
}
```

My problem is here:

```
new MenuItem("Make A Move", board.MakeMove)
```

I get "Expected a method with 'EMenuNavigation MakeMove()' signature"

Method in Board class:

```
public class Board
{

    public EMenuNavigation MakeMove()
    {

        var userMove = GetUserCoords("What do checker you want to move?");

        Console.WriteLine(userMove);
        
        return EMenuNavigation.Stay;
    }
}
```

Problem: Why is "Expected a method with 'EMenuNavigation MakeMove()' signature" if i already have it in class Board and how i can solve it?

If i change

```
Func<EMenuNavigation>?
```

To

```
Func<int>?
```

Everything could work, but it will not be easy readable and hard to understand what number what means.
If i try to change my

```
gameMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Make A Move", board.MakeMove));
```

To

```
gameMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Make A Move", board.MakeMove()));
```

I get another error and cannot solve it too.

Comment: Please don't add your code here in pictures, use the editor to add the code as text. Also only add relevant code here, didn't open the images but it seems there are quite many of them.

Comment: is it possible that you have two EMenuNavigation types in your solution and you reference the wrong one?

Comment: As you use `Func<>` in the ctor of `MenuItem`, so try this : `gameMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Make A Move", () => board.MakeMove() ));` ?

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expression solves problem.

```
gameMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Make A Move", () => board.MakeMove() ));
```